# PHP $_POST in quiz code

Tags: php, mysql, post

Hi seniors and professionals,

I'm not perfect in php. Trying to develop a quiz application from a script i found on some tutorials website. Though i understood the code but one line giving me problem. Following is the code:

```
    $right_answer=0;
    $wrong_answer=0;
    $unanswered=0; 

   $keys=array_keys($_POST);
   var_dump($keys);
   $order=join(",",$keys);

   //$query="select * from questions id IN($order) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)";
  // echo $query;exit;
   $database2 = new Database();
   $response="select id,answer from questions where id IN($order) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)";
   $database2->query($response);
   $res = $database2->resultset();
   foreach($res as $result){
       if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']]){
               $right_answer++;
           }else if($_POST[$result['id']]==5){
               $unanswered++;
           }
           else{
               $wrong_answer++;
           }
   }
```

I tried my best but could not understand the following code:

```
if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']])
```

I found entire script but could not find the post variable sent from form. Please help me. I dont even know my method of asking is right or wrong. Its my first time to stackover flow so i made any mistake please accept my apology.

Comment: please post your form html as well.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right, Are you having trouble understanding what  the line of code does, or is it generating an' error when you execute/load the php?

Comment: That line is comparing the answer field in the database with the input of the form that has the name of the row's id. So to get a match the text in the input should match the text in the answer field exactly.

Comment: $_POST is a magic variable, please check some tutorials on php basics.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. the script is not generating any error, its working fine. But im trying to understand that $_POST[$result['id']] should contain the id from database not from the post variable or may be im wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Replace these lines:

```
if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result['id']]){
     $right_answer++;
}else if($_POST[$result['id']]==5){
    $unanswered++;
}
```

with these:

```
if($result['answer']==$_POST[$result]['id']){
    $right_answer++;
} else if($_POST[$result]['id']==5){
    $unanswered++;
}
```